# Change DIV CSS when element find()

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items with the class `.tweet` and if a certain term is found in that instance of `.tweet`, I want the background of that element.

Problem is, when `jQuery` finds one instance of the keyword, all of the `.tweet` elements change their background. How do I isolate it to the element with the found term?

```
if($('.tweet').find('goat')){
    $('.tweet',this).css('background-color','#663399');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.tweet:contains("goat")')       // find tweets with the word goat within
  .css('background-color','#639'); // change only their background
```

I believe that's what you want. Unless you're looking for a `<goat>` element, `.find` isn't what you need, it's [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). And because you're "chaining" the statement, it will only apply the css style to elements that were matched.

And, for reference, the above code is essentially doing:

```
$('.tweet').each(function(){               // go through each .tweet
  var $tweet = $(this);                    // a reference to the single tweet
  if ($tweet.text().indexOf('goat') != -1){// check if the word "goat" is within
    $tweet.css('background-color','#639'); // change the background color
  }
});
```

Comment: `.contains()` and `:contains` don't do the same thing at all. Your initial codeblock is definitely correct (obviously I'm not going to argue about that when I posted the same thing - first), but your second codeblock won't work with `.contains()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Indeed, forgot to check against `length`. Good catch, and fixed. Thank you.

Comment: what if at the same time you wanted to change the css of an anchor element within .tweet?

Comment: @ok1ha: Using my example, you could also append/chain `.find('a').css(...)`. So it's more: `$tweet.css(...).find('a').css(...);`

Comment: You do need the `.length` check in a general sense, but I meant that the `.contains()` function doesn't search for text, it tests whether one DOM element is contained by another DOM element - at least, that's what the doco page you linked to says...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Oops, you're right. Mental relapse, I blame coffee deprivation. That should be better, now I use a combination of `.text()` & `.indexOf`

Answer (score 2):

If `this` is the element that you've found containg "goat" then you can select its associated ancestor ".tweet" element and change its colour like this:

```
$(this).closest('.tweet').css('background-color','#663399');
```

Although your syntax for the [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is wrong - you've set it to look for a "goat" element, not an element containing the text "goat".

Also your `if` statement's condition will *always* be true(thy), because the `.find()` method always returns a jQuery object (even though sometimes that object is empty).

If your intention is to change the colour of any ".tweet" elements that contain the text "goat" try the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$(".tweet:contains(goat)").css('background-color','#663399');

// OR
var searchTerm = "goat";
$(".tweet:contains(" + searchTerm + ")").css('background-color','#663399');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the :contains selector. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/a9X7b/

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Broadcom</li>
    <li>Cisco</li>
</ul>


$(function(){
    $("ul li:contains('Cisco')").css("background","#eee");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.tweet',this).each(function(i,e){
   if($(e).find('goat'))
      $(e).css('background-color','#663399');
});
```